# How to display all users in a table using VueJs and Axios?

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js

I'm trying to display my users from database (MYSQL) to a table in vueJs.
In below code I tried to display the users in table but it displays nothing. Also when I to ***console.log*** I can see

- Array(4) 0: {…} 1: {…} 2: {…} 3: {…}

and each time I clicked 0: {…}, I see my JSON. What should I do to display this code in my table.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">List of users</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>user.url</td>
              <td>user.lastaname</td>
              <td>user.email</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in script

```
<script>
import QrcodeVue from "qrcode.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {

      users: [],

    };
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get("localhost:2000/user/")
        .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));

  },
  components: {
    QrcodeVue
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("localhost:2000/user/")
      .then(response => {
        this.results = response.data[1];
        console.log(this.results);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

P.S

I tried to follow this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111197/fetch-all-users-and-display-them-with-vue-js) that was asked also here in StackOverflow.

EDIT: This is the output [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGv5Y.jpg)

Comment: Hi, you said that is failed, what is currently displayed with these code an error or nothing ?

Comment: Hi @Toothgip it displays nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot curly brackets !

Here is the code with it :

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">List of users</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>{{ user.url }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been debugging for a long time. Thanks!